# Meaning of the notation $ \sup_{E \subset R} |P(X = E ) - P(Y = E)| $ where $X, Y$ take values in the same finite space $R$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let ${\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}}$ be two random variables taking values in the same finite space ${R}$. I would like to prove an inequality of the form:

$\displaystyle  \frac{1}{2} A \leq \sup_{E \subset R} |{\mathbb P}( \mathbf{X} = E ) - {\mathbb P}( \mathbf{Y} = E )| \leq A$, for some $A \geq  0$ and  $E \subset R$.   How can I write

$ |{\mathbb P}( \mathbf{X} = E ) - {\mathbb P}( \mathbf{Y} = E )|$   what does it mean?

(EDIT: Nov. 20, 2019, 21:03 GMT-3. I changed the inequality for $A$ it is in fact  $ A \geq 0$. )

Comment: I believe you mean $\mathbb P(X\subset E) - \mathbb P(Y\subset E)$. Since $E$ is a set, as opposed to a number, the expression $\mathbb P(X=E)$ doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality is present as the **Exercise 23** on [Terry Tao's Blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/11/12/254a-notes-9-second-moment-and-entropy-methods/) where the value $A$ is the total variation distance $d_{TV}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$ defined by:

$d_{TV}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}) := \sum_{r \in R} | {\mathbb P}( \mathbf{X} = r ) - {\mathbb P}( \mathbf{Y} = r ) |$.

Defining $E \subset R$ where $R$ is a finite space. I don't know how to solve this problem but maybe we could write that as:

$\frac{1}{2} d_{TV}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}) \leq \sup_{e \in E \subset R} |{\mathbb P}(\mathbf{X} = e ) - {\mathbb P}( \mathbf{Y} = e)| \leq d_{TV}(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})$.

Comment: @VictorDelgaldo thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The question has changed.

Answer for the  old version: With the information you have provided we cannot prove such an inequality. Take $X=Y$ to see that the lower bound is not possible.

Answer for the revised version:  We can just take $A=\sup_{E \subset R} |P(X=E)-P(Y=E)|$.  believe the question has been mis-quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kabo Murphy. It is in fact $A \geq 0$.  The point is not with the proof. But the meaning of $ |P(X = E) - P(Y = E)|$ where $X$ is a random variable and $E$ is a subset of $R$.